# sign xml string java

Tags: java, certificate, encryption

how can i encrypt/decrypt string with cer file and private key in java do the certificate need to be in special format?

Abdul Khaliq

Comment: You question would be much better if it was more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking for implementation of XMLEnc specification. Try [XMLSec](http://www.aleksey.com/xmlsec/).

BTW you need to distinguish signing and encrypting operations. These are different standards (XMLDSig and XMLEnc), [partially] different  technologies and often different libraries.

Comment: Interesting. I don't see XML, but maybe you've seen other people use this particular terminology.

Comment: @bmargulies the question is "sign xml string java". I am wondering how you are missing XML part in it.

Answer (score 1):

The [bouncy castle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/) web site is a place to start.